# How to implement Quasar q-table with server-side pagination?

Tags: vue.js, django-rest-framework, vuex, quasar-framework

I am trying to implement server-side pagination for a Quasar QTable, using Vuex and Django Rest Framework as the backend. I am struggling to interpret the documentation for my use case. Currently, I can get the correct number of pages and the first page of results, but the rows-per-page value and the pagination itself does not work. The Quasar docs say there is an @request  event but I'm unsure how to incorporate this into my code.

What am I please missing to make this work?

```
**Vue**

<template>
<q-table
  title="Matches"
  :rows="matches.results"
  :columns="columns"
  v-model:pagination="pagination"
  row-key="id"
>
  <template v-slot:body-cell-actions="props">
    <q-td :props="props">
      <router-link class="action-links" :to="{ name: 'Match', params: { id: props.row.id } }">Details</router-link>
    </q-td>
  </template>
</q-table>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {    
  data() {
    return {
      columns: [
        { name: 'team', label: 'Team', align: 'left', field: 'team', sortable: true, required: true },
        { name: 'date', label: 'Date', align: 'left', field: 'formatted_date', sortable: true },
        { name: 'actions', label: 'Actions', align: 'left', field: '' }
      ]
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch('matches/getMatches')
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      matches: state => state.matches.matches,
      pagination: state => state.matches.pagination
    })
  },
  methods: {}
}
</script>
```

.

```
**Vuex**

import { api } from 'boot/axios'

export const state = {
  matches: [],
  pagination: {
    sortBy: 'desc',
    descending: false,
    page: 1,
    rowsPerPage: 1,
    rowsNumber: 0
  }
}

export const mutations = {
  SET_MATCHES(state, matches) {
    state.matches = matches
    state.pagination.rowsNumber = matches.count
  }

export const actions = {
  getMatches({ commit }) {
    api
      .get(`/api/v1/matches/?page=${state.pagination.page}`)
      // returns object like this:
      // {
      //    count: 6,
      //    next: "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/matches/?page=3",
      //    previous: null,
      //    results: [...]
      // }
      .then(response => {
        commit('SET_MATCHES', response.data)
      })
  }
```

.

```
**Backend**

class MatchPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 2

class MatchViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MatchSerializer
    queryset = Match.objects.all()
    pagination_class = MatchPagination
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a script in the Quasar documentation [Server side pagination, filter and sorting](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/table#server-side-pagination-filter-and-sorting). It shows stubs for the functions needed for server side pagination (`onRequest`, `fetchFromServer`, `getRowsNumberCount`).

In the methods section, you should define `onRequest`, which will be called from the framework if you provide it as a callback for the `@request` event (see below). It should update `rowsNumber`, fetch data from the server, and then update the local pagination object.

This is much like your `this.$store.dispatch('matches/getMatches')` call, so try to call this from `onRequest`.

In the `<template>` section, add

```
  @request="onRequest"
```

in order to listen to the `@request` event.